# how to delete a column in a datatable by a single line in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a data table 'A' in a data set with data and i need to get data to another data table 'B' from the data table 'A' without the first column of the data table 'A'

basically i need to drop the first column of the data table and merge it to the second data table.

but this should be done using a single line.

does anybody knows how to do this ???

Thanks...

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Can you show your code please?

Comment: Why using a single line?

Comment: Hope it ain't a client req wherein *only one line of code can be added* ! Does Table B have any records and do the schema match ?

Comment: Smells like homework to me. Or at least a very fundamental misunderstanding of programming principles.

Comment: did u try this `dt.Columns.Remove[dt.Columns.Count - 1];`

Comment: Harith, performance isn't directly related to _how many_ lines of code there are, but _what those lines are doing._ You can write very poor (or well) performing code in a single line or in multiple lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Table.Columns.Remove("columnName");
```

or

```
Table.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer :)

```
DataSet.Table[0].Columns.Remove("Column_Name");
```